# Is it ok to run more than one antivirus program?

Tags: antivirus, clamav

I am running two different anti-virus programs on my Ubuntu system. I know in Windows this is a bad idea as they will cause issues with each other.

I have Clam AV running, and just managed to get Avast working.

Can I run both applications, or just one? Of the two, which is the better to run. I lean towards Avast.

Comment: Suggestion : 1st of all you don't need anti virus in Ubuntu, but if you want to install anti virus install one of them.

Answer (score 2):

First of all running 2 anti virus programs on a system will probably decrease performance, and as octopusgrabbus said in his answer, they will conflict with each others, and probably
cause a lot of false p[positive detections.

Linux almost makes it hard for viruses to run However, you may want to install an Antivirus program, to secure your self if you share/transfer files over the network with Windows machines, or files that you get from friends that have Windows machine, such as documents.  For more information about antivirus programs that run under Ubuntu see [Why do I need anti-virus software?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus)

But if need to have an antivirus program, I would recommend [ClamAV Antivirus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV)

<sup>Some of this information is complements of Ubuntu help</sup>

Comment: thanks for your answers.. I understand about only needing them for windows files but I am using the cloud a lot and share with my otherlaptop which is a Windows machine.. I discovered Ubuntu when figuring out what to do with a dead Vista machine. I also meant - I won't be running the two at the same time.. just one.. will the existance of the other on my laptop in its dormant state cause problems? I just ran Avast and it came up clear

Comment: sorry - not used to the format f this forum - just saw the answer beneath my question from Qasim..

Comment: My favorite thing about Vista is that it introduced me to Ubuntu. :)

Comment: I have been running Linux for quite a long time, since before Ubuntu was a distro, and I have never seen a virus. I think antivirus software is helpful only on file (samba) servers and mail servers. Otherwise, keep the antivirus software on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the two anti-virus programs do not collide with each other, it probably is not a problem, but you would have to know something about how each anti-virus works.

Depending on how robust your system is, running one anti-virus program logically consumes some system resources, so running two anti-virus programs will consume more. You will have to decide if that is worth it.

I have asked a lot of questions over the years about the need to run Linux/Unix a anti-virus program, and basically have been told that unless I was hosting a shared drive for Windows users, running Linux anti-virus was overkill, and, at one time, I had purchased [NOD32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESET_NOD32), which is quite good and well know on Windows and Linux.

Of course, things change, and hopefully someone else will weigh in on this question.